# python install wheel leads to import error

Tags: python-3.x, pip, python-wheel

I'd like to make a wheel binary distribution, intstall it and then import it in python. My steps are

- I first create the wheel: `python ./my_package/setup.py bdist_wheel`
- I install the wheel: `pip install ./dist/*.whl`
- I try to import the package: `python -c"import my_package"`

This leads to the error:
`ImportError: No module named 'my_package'`

Also, when I do `pip list`, the `my_package` is listed.
However, when I run `which my_packge`, nothing is shown.

When I run `pip install ./my_package/` everything works as expected.

How would I correctly build and install a wheel?

python version 3.5
pip version 10.1
wheel version 0.31.1

**UPDATE:**

When I look at the files inside my_package-1.0.0.dist-info, there is an unexpected entry in `top_level.txt`. It is the name of the folder where I ran 
`python ./my_package/setup.py bdist_wheel` in. I believe my `setup.py` is broken.

**UPDATE WITH REGARDS TO ACCEPTED ANSWER:** 
I accepted the answer below. Yet, I think it is better to simply `cd` into the package directory. Changing to a different directory as suggested below leads to unexpected behavior when using the `-d` flag, i.e. the target directory where to save the wheel. This would be relative to the directory specified in the setup.py file.

Comment: Do you have the `wheel` module? `pip install wheel`

Comment: thanks @rassar, Yes, wheel is installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to execute the setup script from another directory, ensure you are entering the project dir in the script.

```
from setuptools import setup

root = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(__file__), os.pardir))
os.chdir(root)

# or using pathlib (Python>=3.4):
import patlib
root = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent
os.chdir(str(root))

setup(...)
```

Comment: `import pathlib, os` and 

`setup(
    name='test'
)`

makes this snippet executable

Answer (score 4):

I had the very same error, but it was due to my setup.py not specifying the entry "packages=setuptools.find_packages()".
Everythings builds nicely without that but you can't import anything even though pip shows it to be installed.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, in order to solve it I just had to upgrade pip (since Docker installed pip 9).

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same situation, maybe not for the same reason, here just for reference.
The package name should not contain the dash "-", there's no error pop out, but after installing your wheel, though it is shown in pip list, you can't find that package.

> /src/your-package-name  # should not

> /src/your_package_name  # should like this

In the setup.py, you can use the name with dash "-" without limitation:

```
setuptools.setup(
name="instrument-lab",
...
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is using `pyproject.toml` and `setuptools` in conjunction with `setup.py` and `setup.cfg`, there is a note in the documentation that eluded me for quite a while. Standard directory structures for packages will be auto-detected, but if you are using a non-standard directory structure you may need to find packages, or list them explicitly. I was using what I thought was a standard directory structure, but it was not:

```
/path/to/myproject/
    ├── mypackage/                  Python package directory.
    │   ├── __init__.py             This makes the directory a package.
    │   └── example_module.py       An example module.
    ├── pyproject.toml              Definition of build process of the package.
    ├── README.md                   README with info of the project.
    └── setup.cfg                   Configuration details of the python package.
```

What I had to do in `pyproject.toml` was either this:

```
[tool.setuptools]
packages = ["mypackage"]
```

or this:

```
[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["."]
```

Another point of confusion that may arise is that the name of the wheel installed by pip (ie derived from 'myproject') and which `pip list` subsequently shows as simply 'myproject', is not the importable package (ie 'mypackage').