# Building a python wheel : "no module named ______"

Tags: python, python-import, python-module, python-packaging, python-wheel

I am trying to build a python wheel on a complex program, and I have issues with imports. So I managed to reproduce it on a elementary example. The program works fine when directly called, but does not works when trying to import it from an installed wheel.

Here is my example structure :

```
wheel_test
|-setup.py
|-toto
  |-__init__.py
  |-main.py
  |-tata.py
  |-subfolder
    |-__init__.py
    |-titi.py
```

**main.py**

```
# coding: utf8
from tata import tata
import subfolder.titi as titi

def test_fct():
  t1 = tata()
  print(f't1 number = {t1.random_number}')
  print(f'Is t1 number even: {titi.is_even(t1.random_number)}')

test_fct()
```

(Here `t1` is an instance of class `tata`, which just store a random number in `self.random_number`, and the `titi.py` file just contains an `is_even(number)` function, telling if a number is even or not)

This runs just fine when launched :

```
>  python "some_path\wheel_test\toto\main.py"
t1 number = 11
Is t1 number even: False
```

But then, I want to make a wheel of this, using a setup file :
**setup.py**

```
# coding: utf8
import os
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

root = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(__file__), os.pardir))
os.chdir(root)

setup(
  name='toto',
  packages=find_packages(),
  version='0.1',
  description='Wheel test',
  author='Arkeen',
  license='None',
)
```

(I copied the `os.chdir` lines from [[this post]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54145873/python-install-wheel-leads-to-import-error))

This create a `toto-0.1-py3-none-any.whl` file. I then run `$ pip install path_to_newly_created_whell/toto-0.1-py3-none-any.whl`, which seems OK.

But when I want to run this code :

```
# coding: utf8
import toto.main as maintoto
maintoto.test_fct()
```

I got the following error :

```
File "some_path\wheel_test\toto\main.py", line 2, in <module>
  from tata import tata
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tata'
```

So why this outcome ? Why does this code runs fine with python but not as a wheel ?

---

**Edit** : Thanks @Countour-Integral for pointing me the right direction. Still, I had to go deeper into Python `modules`, `packages`, relative and absolute `import` to fully understand this. So, to anyone here having a similar issue, I would recommend to read this :

- [Python Modules and Packages – An Introduction](https://realpython.com/python-modules-packages/)
- [Absolute vs Relative Imports in Python](https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a `ModuleNotFoundError` because the interpreter is searching for a global module named `tata`, and not looking in the current directory. You are also repeating this behavior, in your first code block.

In the following snippet you are running `main.py` as `python path/to/main.py`

```
import subfolder.titi as titi # Does not throw any error
```

the reason this does not throw any error is because, you are **not** running `main` as a package, so when you reference `subfolder` it checks in your current working directory.

Instead when you try to run `setup.py` to build, the interpreter will run everything as a package, and thus, will not look in any local directories. You'll have to change your imports like this

```
# notice the .
from .subfolder import titi 
from .tata import tata
```

Your file structure looks something like this

```
-> module (directory)
---- main.py
---- tata.py
----> subfolder (directory)
-------- titi.py
```

to run any of these as a module, instead of using `python main.py` you'll have to cd 1 step back, into the parent directory of `module` and use `python -m module main.py`,**and make sure that you are using imports with . to refrence files in the same directory**. Normally this is how development of python-pip packages is done, in order to make it easier in the `setup.py` proccess.

Comment: Thanks, I eventually got it :)