# Python module not found after building wheel

Tags: python, package, python-wheel

I've got a very simple wheel file I'm building, which seems to build okay, but it relies on a separate `config.py` module that is called upon import, which is failing after `pip` installing the wheel file.

Research done: [Building a python wheel : "no module named ______"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65077663/building-a-python-wheel-no-module-named) (I can't discern where I'm deviating from that advice)

Project structure:

```
/easypki
    /easypki
        /__init__.py
        /config.json
        /config.py
        /easypki.py
   README.md
   setup.py
```

Contents of `__init__.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
__version__ = "0.1"

from . easypki import EasyPKI  # main class
from . config import Config  # configuration class
```

Contents of `setup.py`:

```
import pathlib
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

__here__ = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent
README = (__here__ / "README.md").read_text()

setup(
    name="easypki",
    version="0.1",
    description="Even simpler client PKI cert interface",
    long_description=README,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    url="https://wherever",
    author="me",
    author_email="my@email.com",
    license="MIT",
    classifiers=[
            "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
            "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
            "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.7"
    ],
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    install_requires=["requests", "requests_pkcs12"],
)
```

I am almost 100% sure that I'm going wrong in `__init__.py` but am having trouble figuring out exactly what needs changed.

EDIT: adding full error message:

```
>>> import easypki
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\easypki\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from . easypki import EasyPKI
  File "C:\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\easypki\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from config import Config
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'
```

EDIT 2:

I ended up getting this working, however I'm not entirely sure why.  I believe it has something to do with how the import call to the `config.Config` class was being made from *within* `easypki.py`:

```
from config import Config
```

So I did a couple things:

1. I moved the `config.Config` import call to within `easypki.EasyPKI` `__init__()` method.
2. I switched the import call to `from .config import Config`
3. I removed the line `from .config import Config` from `__init__.py` as the `config.Config` class is not (yet) meant to be set directly but is just reading whatever's in `config.json`.

Comment: Can you include the full error message.

Comment: @JohnGordon done.

Comment: The error message has `from config import Config`, but the code sample has `from . config import Config`.  Which is it?

Comment: @JohnGordon I edited/updated a bit more.  I *think* I got a little vertigo because I was importing the `Config` class from within `easypki.py`.  As I don't want/need to expose the Config class succinctly, I just dropped it from `__init__.py` and edited the import call with a relative path prefix.  Not sure I could explain why it all ended up working, but it did.